# SMS Retriever API not working in emulator

Tags: android, sms, google-play-services

```
@Override
public void startClient(final Callback callback) {
    SmsRetrieverClient client = SmsRetriever.getClient(context);
    client.startSmsRetriever();
    Task<Void> task = client.startSmsRetriever();
    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            callback.onSuccess();
        }
    });
    task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            callback.onFail(e);
        }
    });
}
```

The code above is the suggested way Google encourages to use their SMS Reytriever API. This method is meant to start a client before the  BroadcastReceiver looks for incoming sms messages. The problem here is that onSuccess and onFailure are never called, none of them, and only happens with a Android emulators. I put some breakpoints and logs to confirmed this, the client never notifies back what happened.

This is not a hash problem since this is only related to the initialization of the SmsRetrieverClient.

I'm really confused and don't know what's happening. To never notify a listener is a behaviour nobody would expect, I'm even thinking that this problem might be related to other factors since I recenlty formatted my computer and re-installed latest Android Studio, because before that this code was working on both emulators and physical devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the redundant `client.startSmsRetriever();` in the second line.

Make sure the play services version on your emulator/device is > **10.2.0**

You can check the play services version using -

```
private static final String MIN_SUPPORTED_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION = "10.2";

public static boolean isSmsRetrieverApiAvailable(Context context) {

    if (!isPlayServicesAvailable(context)) {
        return false;
    }

    try {
        String playServicesVersionName = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(GoogleApiAvailability.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_PACKAGE, 0).versionName; // should be >10.2.0
        return playServicesVersionName.compareTo(MIN_SUPPORTED_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION) > 0;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

private static boolean isPlayServicesAvailable(Context context) {
    GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
    return resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
```

Comment: Thank you, I totally missed the Play Services version part.